# Apply function on coordinate pair along particular axis using multiple variables in Xarray

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, dask, python-xarray

My xarray `Dataset` has three dimensions,

- `x`,`y`,`t`

and 2 variables,

- `foo`, `bar`

I would like to apply function `baz()` on every `x`, `y` coordinate pair's time  series `t`

`baz()` will accept an array of `foo`-s and and array of `bar`-s for a given (`x`, `y`)

I'm having a tough time understanding whether or not built in structures to handle/distribute this exists in either, xarray, pandas, numpy, or dask.

Any hints?

My current approach is writing a python array iterator, or exploring ufunc:

- The issues with iterating over something in python is that I have to deal with concurrency myself and that there is overhead in the iteration.
- The issues with ufunc is that I don't understand it enough and seems like it's a function that is applied to individual elements of the array, not subsets along axes.

The hopeful part of me is looking for something that is xarray native or daskable.

Comment: A real world example here would help a lot.

Comment: Unrelated to what I actually need this for, I've come up with a dummy example. 
 Lets say I have gridded population data spanning 30 years at a resolution of 1 year. For an area that is X by Y. For each (x,y) elem XY, I want to run linear regression on 30 time-stamped values for that specific coordinate.  The result is a grid that stores the slope of each regression. This would represent a filtered linear population growth for that given area and highlight high population growth rather than just high populations.

Comment: In my case. It's high dimensional time series stats. Hence the need for multiple variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds (vaguely) like you are looking for [`Dataset.reduce`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.reduce.html):

```
ds.reduce(baz, dim=('x', 'y'))
```

Comment: This is an interesting idea. I'll play around with it. I can be more specific( if you think I worded my problem vaguely)

Comment: A [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help. And a clear definition of the output you would like to have. :-)